# ArrayList<String> order by name

Tags: android, arraylist

i am facing 3 problems with my ArrayList. It reads without any problem files from my sdcard.

Files have this structure:

```
1.3.2016.csv
2.3.2016.csv
29.2.2016.csv
30.2.2016.csv
4.2.2016.csv
```

Here is my method to read files from sdcard:

```
private List<String> getList(File parentDir) {

    ArrayList<String> inFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] fileNames = parentDir.list();
    for (String fileName : fileNames) {
        if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")) {
            inFiles.add(removeLastChar(fileName));
        } else {
            File file = new File(File.separator + fileName + ".csv");
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                inFiles.addAll(getList(((file))));
            }
        }
    }

    itemTexte.addAll(Arrays.asList(fileNames));
    return inFiles;
}

private static String removeLastChar(String str) {
    return str.substring(0,str.length()-4);
}
```

And here is what i call from onCreate:

```
List<String> files = getList(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Test" + File.separator + "Files"));
```

1. First problem. I don't want to see the ".csv" in my recycler view. So i try to remove 4 chars from it (see removeLastChar method). But it stays at ".csv" at the end no matter what i do.
2. I want to order the recycler view, by the name of the files. For now it does not order it by the name. I tried the method Comparator, but i didn't understood how, i should parse my elements there.
3. Even if my files don't have the ending ".csv", they are still shown in the recycler view. Looks like it catch all files that are in the folder.

**UPDATE**
I can sort my list with this(thanks guys):

```
    Collections.sort(inFiles);
```

But it sorts kind of wrong...
Example:

```
1.3.2016
10.2.2016
11.4.2016
2.3.2016
3.3.2016
```

But it should be something like this:

```
10.2.2016
1.3.2016
2.3.2016
3.3.2016
11.4.2016
```

Is there any easy fix? Or should i implement writing "0" to the files when user create it?

**UPDATE 2**

So i added this

```
Collections.sort(inFiles, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            String[] s1Values = s1.split(".");
            String[] s2Values = s1.split(".");
            //define your comparison, arrays will have each value between '.', e.g. {"1", "3", "2016", "csv" } for "1.3.2016.csv"
            int compare_result = s1.compareTo(s2);
            return compare_result; //return -1 if s1 < s2, 0 if equal, 1 if s1 > s2
        }
    });
```

My list looks like this

```
01.04.2016
02.04.2016
15.04.2016
16.03.2016
```

But the 16.03.2016 should be first...
Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Your remove file extension method should work. I think your issue is that you don't add your new list to the `itemTexte`, you add the original list of files.

Change

```
itemTexte.addAll(Arrays.asList(fileNames));
```

to

```
itemTexte.addAll(inFiles );
```

**2.**

```
Collections.sort(inFiles);
```

**3.** See the fix for #1

Comment: Please see the updated question. It worked almost how it should. Only sort function is wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, I remember that! It's not the first time... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java, it helps to me a lot!

Comment: @Wladislaw You will want to use a comparator. i will update my answer with an example.

Comment: @Wladislaw I've edited my answer, but left some of the implementation of the comparator out, as it will be up to you to decide on how to order them.

Comment: @JamesWierzba can you check what is wrong with the code from you? I mean when i implement it, it looks like it does not even sort it...look the updated question.

Comment: @Wladislaw you return 1 every time, which means you are saying, `s1` is always greater than `s2`. you need to find out which string (`s1` or `s2`) is greater, and return the appropriate value.

Comment: @JamesWierzba i am sorry... can you give more hint, how i can get second parameter (month) to sort too...with more priority? Look the updated question...

Comment: @Wladislaw Ok, I've implemented it for you, please see my new answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is and more complete example of a comparator for you to use to sort your special file names.

I've added checks in-case the file is not in the form "*.*.*"

```
    Collections.sort(inFiles, new Comparator<String>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            String[] s1Values = s1.split("\\.");
            String[] s2Values = s2.split("\\.");
            //compare the year
            if(s1Values.length >= 3 && s2Values.length >= 3)
            {
                int compare = s1Values[2].compareTo(s2Values[2]);
                if(compare != 0) return compare;
            }
            //compare the month
            if(s1Values.length >= 2 && s2Values.length >= 2)
            {
                int compare = s1Values[1].compareTo(s2Values[1]);
                if(compare != 0) return compare;
            }
            //compare the day
            if(s1Values.length >= 1 && s2Values.length >= 1)
            {
                int compare = s1Values[0].compareTo(s2Values[0]);
                if(compare != 0) return compare;
            }
            return 0; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**. You should use `split` to catch just fileName, I will show you an example right down

**2**. To sort alphabetically do `java.util.Collections.sort(listOfCSV)`

```
String string = "fileName.csv";
String[] parts = string.split(".");
String firstPart = parts[0]; // fileName
String secondPart = parts[1]; // csv
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please see the updated question. It worked almost how it should. Only sort function is wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, I remember that! It's not the first time... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java, it helps to me a lot! It's so simple, using Comparator<String>