# How to sort ArrayList according to Date which is in string format?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compareto

this is exact duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java) but there is one tricky difference.
I have an ArrayList of type 'LOBServiceRequestDetails' which gets updated with values from web service. Some of the varriables of LOBServiceRequestDetails are as below,

- String#agentId
- String#creationDate (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss format)

I want sort this list according to creationDate. One way I have is implement Comparable in LOBServiceRequestDetails model class and override compareTo method, but due to some issues I can't change this class. So I used Collection.sort as follow,

```
     DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
     Collections.sort(lOBServiceRequestDetailsList, new Comparator<LOBServiceRequestDetails>() {
          public int compare(LOBServiceRequestDetails o1, LOBServiceRequestDetails o2) {
              if (o1.getCreationDate() == null || o2.getCreationDate() == null)
                    return 0;
              try{
                  return sdf.parse(o1.getCreationDate()).compareTo(sdf.parse(o2.getCreationDate()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
          }
        });
```

But this is not working as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Expected output:

[LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=22/05/2017 10:31:20**, agentId=ag11], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=07/02/2017 11:10:20**, agentId=ag12], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=06/12/2016 12:51:20**, agentId=ag13], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=17/12/2015 06:44:20**, agentId=ag14]]

Actual output:

[LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=06/12/2016 11:10:20**, agentId=ag11], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=17/12/2015 06:44:20**, agentId=ag12], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=07/02/2017 11:10:20**, agentId=ag13], LOBServiceRequestDetails [**creationDate=22/05/2017 10:31:20**, agentId=ag14]]

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: you're using o1.getCreationDate() on both side of the compareTo

Comment: @DavisMolinari Edited code but still not getting sorted List

Comment: @Aominè its of String type as I have mentioned.

Comment: Just for the records: you should convert datestrings to `Date` objects as soon as you get them from the user. If you get this datestrings from the database: **change the data model** to use date type there too. Otherwise you will run in to trouble in the long run!

Comment: You're logic when a date is null seems off for me. When you compare any date wil null you allways say they are both equal. Lets say you have 3 "Dates", A:"1.1.1000", B:"2.2.1000" and C: null. Where would you sort the null value into this list?  After all A<B but A=C and B=C. This goes against the compareto contract. You should have your compareTo method return different values when only one of the values is null. (eG: o1!=null and o2=null return 1, o1=null and o2=null return 0 and if o1=null and o2!=null return -1

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I think you have not understood the problem. Here date is in String and any of the value from response is null, i am simple retaining the list.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle It seems good approach to convert datestrings to Date objects as soon get them from the user. Thanks.

Comment: @VikasYadav I have understood the problem. It doesn't matter whether you are dealing with a String or Date your compareTo method must be consistent and you have to decide where you should order the null values to (beginning or end of list or even something weird like treating them as a specific date). By always returning 0 in your compareTo method when one of the arguments is null you are not "retaining the list" but messing up the order algorythm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort Date which is in string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java)

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Yes I have mentioned at first line of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using o1.getCreationDate() on both side of the compareTo:

```
   return sdf.parse(o1.getCreationDate()).compareTo(sdf.parse(o1.getCreationDate()));
```

Edit: This fixed one problem but ther's still an error in the way null values are handled because, as explained in the comment by "OH GOD SPIDERS", if one of the two dates is null they're considered equal.
If you for example change your condition in this way:

```
              if (o1.getCreationDate() == null) return 1;
              if (o2.getCreationDate() == null) return -1;
          try{...
```

you get null values to be put at the end of the list.

Screenshot of the output matching your expected result
[image]

Comment: @VikasYadav I tried the correct code (with o2) and it's working as expected

Comment: @DavisMolinari did your test data containe some dates that were `null`?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS  Actually not for the first run. I did a second run including some null and in fact it didn't work correctly. The problem is exactly what you explained in your comment above.

Comment: @DavisMolinari Edited question with expected and actual output. No there is no null in response

Comment: @VikasYadav edited the answer with a screenshot with the output matching your expected result

Comment: @Davis yae solved the issue.. it was a silly mistake. I compared o1 with o2 instead of reverse. Thank you.