# Java program to sort a list of date which is in format dd MMM yyyy

Tags: java, sorting, date

Input is a list containing date in String format. I have solution as below. But i feel it can be made more efficient. Any help would be appreciated.

//Map to store month data

```
HashMap<String,String> month = new HashMap<String,String>();
        month.put("Jan","01");
        month.put("Feb","02");
        month.put("Mar","03");
        month.put("Apr","04");
        month.put("May","05");
        month.put("Jun","06");
        month.put("Jul","07");
        month.put("Aug","08");
        month.put("Sep","09");
        month.put("Oct","10");
        month.put("Nov","11");
        month.put("Dec","12");
```

You can consider this as input

```
    String[] input = {"20 Oct 2052",
    "26 May 1960",
    "06 Jun 1933",
    "06 Jun 1933",
    "06 Jun 1933",
};


    ArrayList<Long> temp1 = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

To compare result

```
    HashMap<Long,String> temp2 = new HashMap<Long,String>();

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i< input.length ; i++){
        String j = "";
        if(input[i].length() == 11){

            j+= input[i].substring(7,11);
            j+= month.get(input[i].substring(3,6));
            j+=input[i].substring(0,2);

            temp1.add(Long.parseLong(j));
            temp2.put(Long.parseLong(j), input[i]);   
        }
    }
```

Sorting the result

```
Collections.sort(temp1);
```

Printing the result

```
System.out.println(temp1.toString());
```

Comment: I think **PriorityQueue** would be helpful in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Date which is in string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java)

Comment: I wrote [a new answer to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52776978/5772882). Instead of `LocalDateTime` as in that answer use `LocalDate` (since your dates don’t have time of day), and use a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)`. That should give you the effective and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is your friend. Just sort strings with this algorithm. This is optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would parse the date strings into a Date Object

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse("26 May 1960");
```

You could create an object that holds a Date object then make it comparable.

```
public class DateContainer implements Comparable<DateContainer > {
 private Date dateTime;

 public DateContainer (Date date){
  this.dateTime = date;
 }

 public Date getDateTime() {
  return dateTime;
 }

 public void setDateTime(Date datetime) {
  this.dateTime = datetime;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(DateContainer o) {
   return getDateTime().compareTo(o.getDateTime());
 }
}
```

Then you could create a list of the Object above then use Collections to sort it

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: So that's true, there are better implementations. But for the purpose of this question when they are just using Strings, anything solution is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    String[] input = {"20 Oct 2052",
            "26 May 1960",
            "06 Jun 1933",
            "06 Jun 1933",
            "06 Jun 1933",
    };
    Map<Long, String> result = new TreeMap<>();
    Stream.of(input)
            .filter(s -> s.length() == 11)
            .forEach(s -> {
                try {
                    result.put(f.parse(s).getTime(), s);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Format: " + s);
                }
            });
    System.out.println(result); // {-1154156400000=06 Jun 1933, -303033600000=26 May 1960, 2612970000000=20 Oct 2052}
}
```

Use SimpleDateFormat to get Date value and TreeMap to sorted elements in the map.

Hope that help you!!!!

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

List<Date> dates = Arrays.stream(input).map(dateString -> {
try {
    return simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
dates.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

dates.forEach(date -> System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date)));
```

this is a 2 step process

1. Convert to java.util.Date
2. Sort the Date list and Print

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

This is a one-liner using modern *java.time* classes and lambda syntax.

Parse each string into a `LocalDate`, collect, sort, and regenerate strings as output.

```
Arrays.stream(
        new String[] { "20 Oct 2052" , "26 May 1960" , "06 Jun 1933" , "06 Jun 1933" , "06 Jun 1933" }
)
        .map( input -> LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu" , Locale.US ) ) )
        .sorted()
        .map( date -> date.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu" , Locale.US ) ) )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() )
        .toString()
```

> [06 Jun 1933, 06 Jun 1933, 06 Jun 1933, 26 May 1960, 20 Oct 2052]

Steps:

- Generate a stream of your array's elements (the string inputs).
- Process each input, parsing to get a `LocalDate`
- Sort the `LocalDate` objects
- On each `LocalDate`, generate text representing its value.
- Collect each of those generated strings into a `List`.
- Generate text representing the list of strings, now sorted in chronological order.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Use appropriate data types rather than mere strings.

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate` class.

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMM uuuu" , Locale.US );
```

Loop the inputs, parsing each into a `LocalDate`. Collect each resulting `LocalDate` into a `List`.

```
    List < LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList <>( inputs.length );
    for ( String input : inputs ) {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
        dates.add( ld );
    }
```

Or instead, use the short and sweet lambda syntax.

```
List < LocalDate > dates = Arrays.stream( inputs ).map( input -> LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Sort the list of `LocalDate` objects.

```
Collections.sort( dates );
```

Report your sorted dates in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String outputs = dates.toString() ;
```

> [1933-06-06, 1933-06-06, 1933-06-06, 1960-05-26, 2052-10-20]

Report your sorted dates in any desired format.

```
   List < String > outputs = new ArrayList <>( dates.size() );
    for ( LocalDate date : dates ) {
        outputs.add( date.format( f ) );
    }
```

> [06 Jun 1933, 06 Jun 1933, 06 Jun 1933, 26 May 1960, 20 Oct 2052]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).