# How to get max and minimum date in a list dates are like String ''17.03.2020", ''12.03.2020", ''01.02.2020" in java

Tags: java, sorting, date, max, min

```
List<String> dateList=new ArrayList<>();
```

Please help me hopw to get max and min dates in a given list date format is in String format("17.03.2020")

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Did you do any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort Date which is in string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTimeFormatter` to convert the date strings to the corresponding `LocalDate` values and add them to a new `List` which you can sort using `Collections::sort`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu");
        List<String> strDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        strDateList.add("17.03.2020");
        strDateList.add("12.03.2020");
        strDateList.add("01.02.2020");

        List<LocalDate> dateList = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
        for (String ds : strDateList) {
            dateList.add(LocalDate.parse(ds, dateFormatter));
        }
        Collections.sort(dateList);
        System.out.println(dateList);

        // If you want to replace the elements in the original list with sorted values
        strDateList.clear();
        for (LocalDate ld : dateList) {
            strDateList.add(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu")));
        }
        System.out.println(strDateList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2020-02-01, 2020-03-12, 2020-03-17]
[01.02.2020, 12.03.2020, 17.03.2020]
```