# Cannot compare String dates in different Time Zone

Tags: java

Sorry for my ignorance but i can't get the correct result comparing ( sort from the newer to older ) multiple date in different time zone.

i get date from an xml server in this format :

Example :

Wed, 27 May 2020 20:39:02 +0400

Wed, 27 May 2020 19:12:22 +0200

Wed, 27 May 2020 15:31:32 GMT

I tried many solution in internet but always wrong results, thank you for your help

I tried to compare them one by one

```
public boolean isEarlier(String date1,String date2){
        DateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
        //final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
        //format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        //Date date = formatter.parse(date1);

        Date _date2 = null,_date1 = null;
        try {
             _date1 = format.parse(date1);
            _date2 = format.parse(date2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (_date1.compareTo(_date2) <= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but always wrong results

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java

Comment: I tried it, see my edit question but always wrong results

Comment: why are you using the old cumbersome legacy date api instead of `java.time`?

Comment: I can't see difference , i m not used to work with java time, sorry

Comment: I (too) recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `OffsetDateTime.parse("Wed, 27 May 2020 20:39:02 +0400", DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)` yields `2020-05-27T20:39:02+04:00` and works for your other strings too.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. On my Java 8 your code parses your three example strings correctly. Which is your default locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to documentation for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Some of the symbols in your pattern aren't suitable for the sample strings you posted in your question.

Try the following:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx", Locale.ENGLISH);
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed, 27 May 2020 20:39:02 +0400", formatter);
```

*Wed* is day of week in only three letters, hence `EEE`
The pattern also contains the hour in 24 hour format, hence `HH` rather than `kk`
Regarding the month, `MMM` is for three letter month, e.g. *Apr* (for *April*). If you want full name of month, add another `M`, i.e. `MMMM`.

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed, 27 May 2020 13:50:30 GMT' could not be parsed at index 26

Comment: @Singa You can't use the same format for both an offset and a named time zone. Refer to the documentation. Replace `xx` with `VV` for named time zone, like `GMT`.

Comment: Yes i understand, so i will try to change format first, then compare

Comment: Using java.time is a great suggestion. The format is RFC 1123 and the formatter is built-in. So I recommend you neither select nor count format patterns letters. Just use `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`.