# Unable to sort dates. Getting error "Text '' could not be parsed at index 11" even though the date format is correct

Tags: java

I am getting multiple dates from UI which I store in list. I want to sort these dates

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
li.add("11/1/2022 2:59 am");
li.add("10/21/2022 9:33 pm"); li.add("10/20/2022 8:26 am");
```

and so on

I am trying to sort with following code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.US);

Collections.sort(li, (s1, s2) -> LocalDateTime.parse(s1, formatter).
        compareTo(LocalDateTime.parse(s2, formatter)));
```

but getting error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '10/21/2022 9:33 pm' could not be parsed at index 11"

The accepted solution at [How to sort Date which is in string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451976/how-to-sort-date-which-is-in-string-format-in-java) is not working for me. Could anyone please help here?

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy h:mm a", Locale.UK);` does it for me ;)

Comment: Why are you adding strings to your list? That’s bad data modelling. You should make yourself a list of `LocalDateTime` objects (or `ZonedDateTme`) and defer formatting to the time when you display the result to the user.

Comment: @OleV.V. I get this from UI. I am doing UI test automation

Comment: I would still store proper datre-time objects. If you indispensably need the exact string you got from the UI, then objects holding both even though it’s redundant.

Comment: @OleV.V. you mean using List<LocalDateTime>?. Since from the automation it is retrieved in String as it has textContent() method. I thought rather than typecasting it to LocalDateTime let's store it as it is in String. Anyway I have got it working. Can you please provide me reference code so that I can study

Comment: There’s an example of what I suggest [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52776978/5772882).